# Shopify Metafields from a front form (react-hook-form)

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm trying to integrate a private api in a Shopify App.

Today, i'd like to use MetaFields API to save 2 keys from a front-form display on the initialisation page (index.js) of my app.

I tried to use something like this :

```
  const saveKey = async () => {

const fetchFunction = authenticatedFetch(app);

const response = await fetchFunction('/admin/customers/${owner_id}.json', {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    metafield: {
      namespace: "demo",
      key: "playerKey",
      value: "toto",
      type: "single_line_text_field"
    }
  })
})
console.log(response)
```

}
to init a new metafield.

Console.log return a POST 405 error, i'm really lost on this Shopify API, if someone can explain me how can i init a new metafield to store these keys it's really kind.

Have a nice day

Comment: I built an app [FieldsRaven](https://apps.shopify.com/fieldsraven) to make such use case possible. Here is the [quick start guide](https://docs.fieldsraven.app/quick-start).

Answer (score 0):

You can't save Metafields from the front-end without a third party application that has some sort of open post route where you can submit that data securly.

The Private App API is **NOT** to be used on the storefront! You should use only the StoreFront API for any operations but that will not allow you to modify the metafields.

So long story short you can't save any matafields if you don't create yourself a public route (a.k.a a public URL outside of Shopify that will use the Private APP to make an API request to Shopify) that will handle the request securely or if you use a metafield that has a Proxy URL provided in Shopify that you can submit to in order to save metafields.

To simplify:

- Private Apps (back-end) are used for external purpose (example if you want a Wordpress site to make modifications directly in the Shopify via some php code)
- Private Apps (front-end, a.k.a StoreFront API) is used for Headless CMS and it's mainly used for getting data from Shopify
- Custom apps - are self-hosted applications that are tied to a single store and integrated in Shopify
- Public apps - are self-hosted applications that can be tied to multiply stores, integrated in Shopify and require a review process

The only approach that is not viable for your case is the **Private Apps (front-end, a.k.a StoreFront API)**